# Different Case of There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, html-select

I will really appreciate some help with the following.
I am trying to populate a Drop Down from a List and keep getting this error. I read and tried all of the suggestions in the similar titled posts and can't get it work.

in the controller I have:

```
        public ActionResult Search(string stringInput)
    {
        ClassManager manger = new ClassManager();
       ViewData["myList"] =  manger.GetData(stringInput, SearchBy);//Returns List<string>

        return View();
    }
```

In the View I have:

```
@Html.DropDownList("MyList", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["myList"], "Select...")
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

DropDownList is always looking for a list of the SelectListItem type, *not* your specific model instances. This seems to trip up almost everyone.

The solution is to translate the list you want to display (`IEnumerable<string>`) into `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. The easiest approach is something like `ViewData["myList"] = new SelectList(manger.GetData(stringInput, SearchBy))` which may or may not work for your example.

I personally use a ViewModel that consists of the view for the model as one property and the SelectList as another. As I post the result, I pull the elements out and into the respective database/repository calls as necessary. It's a bit of abstraction up front but it feels a little cleaner on the view side.

Comment: I already tried the easy approach you suggested and it does not work. There isno even difference in the error message. Thank you for the ViewModel suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SelectList` to populate a `List<string>` object in a DropDownList

```
@Html.DropDownList("MyList", 
                   new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["myList"]), "Select...")
```

Comment: It doesn't work. First there was an error message that IEnumerable must have type I tried both <string> and <SelectList> gave the same runtime error :Value cannot be null.Parameter name: items

Comment: Are you sure that `manger.GetData(stringInput, SearchBy)` returns a `List<string>`?

Comment: Yes its return type is List<string>

Comment: It works for me. Try to make a `SelectList` in your controller and pass it to the view, maybe the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: where else the problem could be?

Comment: It seems to me that `ViewData["myList"]` don't transfer correctly to the view.